# Identification of rock formation along Wales coast

Tags: regional-geology

I hope that you can help me, my wife and I visited National Trust - Stackpole, Pembrokeshire last week where I took a couple of hundred photos.
I've attached a photo of the coloured cliffs there.  For me to enter this into one of our club competitions I need to know the correct terminology for the rock formation.

[image].

I hope that there is a someone who could let me know

Answer (score 4):

This is Marloes Sand Beach, a classical fossil site. The nicely colored rocks are sandstones of the Silurian age (around 425 million years old). The different dipping angles of the sandstone layers are a result of tectonic processes, which were folding the rocks.

[Further information about Marloes Sand can be found here](https://www.google.de/amp/s/ukfossils.co.uk/2007/10/26/marloes-sands)